In Polars, how can you update several columns simultaneously?
Suppose we have a Polars frame something like this
lf = pl.LazyFrame([
    pl.Series("a", ...),
    pl.Series("b", ...),
    pl.Series("c", ...),
    pl.Series("i", ...)
])

and a function something like this
def update(a, b, c, i):
    s = a + b + c + i
    a /= s
    b /= s
    c /= s
    return a, b, c

that depends of elements of columns a, b, c and also i.
How can we update each row of a frame using the function?
We could use with_columns to update the rows of each column independently but how can we do it with the dependency between columns?
Edit
In response to comments from @roman let's tighten up the question.
Use this LazyFrame
lf = pl.LazyFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("a", [1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=pl.Int8),
        pl.Series("b", [5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=pl.Int8),
        pl.Series("c", [9, 0, 1, 2], dtype=pl.Int8),
        pl.Series("i", [3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=pl.Int8),
        pl.Series("o", [7, 8, 9, 0], dtype=pl.Int8),
    ]
)

We want to update columns a, b & c in a way that depends on column i. Column o should be unaffected. We have a function that takes the values a, b, c & i and returns a, b, c & i, where the first three have been updated but i remains the same as the input. After updating, all columns should have the same dtype as before.
The closest we can get is using an update function like this.
def update(args):
    s = args["a"] + args["b"] + args["c"] + args["i"]
    args["a"] /= s
    args["b"] /= s
    args["c"] /= s
    return args.values()

and applying it like this
(
    lf.select(
        pl.struct(pl.col("a", "b", "c", "i"))
        .map_elements(update, return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Float64))
        .list.to_struct(fields=["a", "b", "c", "i"])
        .alias("result"),
    )
    .unnest("result")
    .collect()
)

But this has some problems.

We have lost column o.
Column i has become Float64
It's pretty ugly.

Is there a better way?

You can use with_columns instead of select so you don’t lose other columns. Or you can add pl.exclude([“a”,”b”,”c”]) to select list

again, question is - are you sure your function cannot be expressed via pure polars expressions? The language is pretty rich now, and it's going to be way more performant

It really depends on what the function does. .with_columns(update(pl.col.a, pl.col.b, pl.col.c, pl.col.i)) "works" for the original example because expressions support those operations and the function is just used as an "expression builder".  If you need to actually materialize the values at the Python level to perform some non-Polars functionality then it becomes a map_(batches|elements) type question which is a bit different.

update
lf.select(
    pl.exclude(["a","b","c"]),
    pl
    .struct(pl.all()).map_elements(update, return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Float64))
    .list.to_struct(fields=["a","b","c"])
    .alias("result")
).unnest("result").collect()

shape: (4, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ i   ┆ o   ┆ a        ┆ b        ┆ c      │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ i8  ┆ i8  ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64    │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 0.055556 ┆ 0.277778 ┆ 0.5    │
│ 4   ┆ 8   ┆ 0.166667 ┆ 0.5      ┆ 0.0    │
│ 5   ┆ 9   ┆ 0.1875   ┆ 0.4375   ┆ 0.0625 │
│ 6   ┆ 0   ┆ 0.2      ┆ 0.4      ┆ 0.1    │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┴────────┘

Or you can update your function to return dictionary and skip the lists:
def update(args):
    s = args["a"] + args["b"] + args["c"] + args["i"]
    args["a"] /= s
    args["b"] /= s
    args["c"] /= s
    return args

lf.select(
    pl
    .struct(pl.all()).map_elements(update, return_dtype=pl.Struct)
    .alias("result")
).unnest("result").collect()

shape: (4, 5)
┌──────────┬──────────┬────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a        ┆ b        ┆ c      ┆ i   ┆ o   │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64    ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞══════════╪══════════╪════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0.055556 ┆ 0.277778 ┆ 0.5    ┆ 3   ┆ 7   │
│ 0.166667 ┆ 0.5      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 4   ┆ 8   │
│ 0.1875   ┆ 0.4375   ┆ 0.0625 ┆ 5   ┆ 9   │
│ 0.2      ┆ 0.4      ┆ 0.1    ┆ 6   ┆ 0   │
└──────────┴──────────┴────────┴─────┴─────┘

original
In general, I'd advice agains using python function and try to stay within pure polars expressions.
So in your case it could look, for example, like this:
lf = pl.LazyFrame([
    pl.Series("a", [1,2,3]),
    pl.Series("b", [2,3,4]),
    pl.Series("c", [5,6,7]),
    pl.Series("i", [7,8,7])
])

(
    lf
    .with_columns(pl.exclude("i") / pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all()))
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ a        ┆ b        ┆ c        ┆ i   │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ i64 │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════╡
│ 0.066667 ┆ 0.133333 ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 7   │
│ 0.105263 ┆ 0.157895 ┆ 0.315789 ┆ 8   │
│ 0.142857 ┆ 0.190476 ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 7   │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────┘

if you really want to pass the function, you can do it:
def update(row):
    a,b,c,i = [row[x] for x in list("abci")]
    s = a + b + c + i
    a /= s
    b /= s
    a /= s
    return a, b, c

lf.select(
    pl.col.i,
    pl
    .struct(pl.all()).map_elements(update, return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Float64))
    .list.to_struct(fields=["a","b","c"])
    .alias("result")
).unnest("result")

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ i   ┆ a        ┆ b        ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════╡
│ 7   ┆ 0.004444 ┆ 0.133333 ┆ 5.0 │
│ 8   ┆ 0.00554  ┆ 0.157895 ┆ 6.0 │
│ 7   ┆ 0.006803 ┆ 0.190476 ┆ 7.0 │
└─────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────┘


That works with the particular update function shown but not for any function of its kind.

@user3414663 please check updated answer

This is certainly getting closer but it passes all columns to update. How can we pass only columns a, b & c, when there are other columns present? I tried struct(['a', 'b', 'c']) but then everything becomes null

But your function uses i column as well or do you want to change the function?

See the edit to the question
